# user dropdown privilege link goes to non-existent page.

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the new username drop-down, if I click on the 'privileges' link here on meta.askubuntu, it directs me to a nonexistent webpage: http://meta.askubuntu.com/privileges .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops -- will get that fixed in the next deploy!